# How can I extract data from one app to use in another app on Ubuntu?

Tags: java, c, ubuntu

For example,there is an app called `System Analyst` that shows me how much data has been downloaded in the current session.I'd like to use this data in another app,which I want to write in C or Java.

Is this a bad idea?If so why?

Comment: Start learning about IPC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

Comment: No, it is not a bad idea. Carry on!

Comment: Has your System Analyst application a way to communicate that information in some way?

Comment: Perhaps the app gathers its information from a file (like from /proc/*). Or it prints data, which you could use for reading them in via a pipe.

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox I don't know whether it has or not.

Comment: @mahsum then it's a bit hard to answer your question, cause I don't know either. It all depends if and where that S/A application stored those data, whether they are accessible or not. In general, intercommunication between processes is perfectly normal, but they have to be designed with that in mind. You give too little information, though, to judge whether your design is correct or not.

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox All I need was a start point.I searched about it to find one but I couldn't.Now,I got IPC to start digging around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it's better to go to the source of the information instead of trusting some other application. In the case of data received and sent, you can get them directly from the kernel by reading `/proc/net/dev`.